# SSH access via network cable

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi

My problem is the following:
I have a Raspberry Pi (Old Model B I think) which I want to be running at some place that doesn't have a LAN or even WLAN and be able to do some configuration. BUT it won't have any human I/O peripherals.

My way to do that would be the following:

1. Plug RPi into power supply.
2. Let it boot and start all the stuff that's commonly needed.

Then, if I needed to change some little thing:

3. Plug network cable into RPi.
4. Plug network cable (the same) into my notebook.
5. Connect via SSH or something.

Step 5. is where I don't have any idea how to accomplish that. Please help me out, give me some links or search terms, anything helps. :)

PS: I have some bash-scripting experience, C, Python, JS, etc. and know a little about Linux stuff.

Comment: Maybe try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: See it as a general question imaged by example. I can change it if you want.